# Cannot initialize union in C++ 11

Tags: c++, c++11, unions

I can't initialize union in std::pair.

I have this kind of typedef

```
enum EValueType
{
    Int,
    Double,
    Variable,
    Unknown
};

union UValueContainer
{
    int __int;
    double __double;
    double* __variable;
};

typedef std::pair<EValueType, UValueContainer> variant;
```

and I have a base class with constructor, which gets a attribute of `variant` type

```
class fooBase
{
    fooBase(variant attribute);
    ...
}
```

and a derived class with constructor, which have to initialize argument of base class constructor.

```
class fooDerived : public fooBase
{
    fooDerived(double* value) : fooBase({Variable, UValueContainer{.__variable = value}}
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: `UValueContainer{.__variable = value}` This syntax is not available in C++ (yet). How about a constructor for the union?

Comment: Do I have to manually declare / define constructors for every type? @DeiDei

Comment: You may try to solve your problem with `std::variant`. If you don't have C++17 compilers and standard libraries, you can try many third party implementations like `absl::variant`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DeiDei commented my post - I declared / defined constructors for each type. Now the problem is solved. But I want to be sure if there is no other way for solving this problem.

Comment: If you can upgrade to C++17, consider using [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) instead. Otherwise, consider [`boost::variant`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/variant.html).

Comment: More detail on how you solved it may be useful here.